# Регулярное выражение для поиска html-тега с определенным значением атрибута class

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Подскажите оптимальное регулярное выражение для такого случая:
в валидном html-тексте требуется отыскать все значения находящиеся в атрибутах href тега `<a>` имеющего класс "xxx".

Примеры подходящих значений:

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="xxx">...</a>
<a class="xxx" href="www.yandex.ru">...</a>
<a class="xxx yyy" href="https://habrahabr.ru" style="border: 1px solid red">...</a>
<a href="http://example.com" class="zzz xxx yyy">
```

Примеры НЕ подходящих значений:

```
<a class="zzz" href="www.ya.ru">...</a> (нет класса xxx)
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">...</a> (нет класса xxx)
```

Текст представляет собой обычную web-страницу, т.е. кроме тегов `<a>` там имеется полный набор и других html-тегов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне придумалось такое выражение

```
<a\s+(?=[^>]*class="[^"]*xxx)[^>]*href="([^"]+)"[^>]*>
```

оно конечно немного ненадежное, но покроет большинство вариантов. Проблема произойдет, если class содержит класс AAAxxxAAA, но не содержит xxx.

Так как Вы не написали, какой язык программирования и библиотека регулярок используется, то я не могу гарантировать, что оно точно заработает. Но на php/perl должно.

Как по мне, то тут лучше использовать парсер html - код будет простой и красивый. И главное, точно реализует задачу.

Comment: В php для точного сравнения можно использовать границу слова `\bword\b`, тогда `AAAxxxAAA` срабатывать не будет

Comment: вокруг нужного вам параметра есть скобочки. И это выражение попадет в первую группу. А в нулевую группу попадает все выражение - это естественно.

Comment: спасибо :) респект!

Comment: Черновой набросок https://regex101.com/r/fZ2gG4/1